# Identifying multivariate outliers in a large sample with missing data, using SPSS

Tags: spss, multivariate-analysis, missing-data, outliers, large-data

I'm a psychology PhD student doing analysis on a relatively large set of data, obtained via online surveys. The purpose of the study is largely to determine normative data for a population of adults, on a number of psychology scales. However, I'm not sure on the best/easiest method of identifying multivariate outliers in my sample, especially since I have missing data.

My sample consists of 1730 participants. Each participant completed ~ 130 questions, which I've made (sub)scale scores for. After creating these scales, I've ended up with ~30 primary variables of interest. This figure (30) has been inflated somewhat because most of the scales I'm using have several subscales, and one scale's 8 items need to be assessed individually.

I have a small-modest amount of missing data. There's <5% missing data for any given variable, but overall I'd estimate that 1/3 of my participants are missing data on at least one of the 30 primary variables.

I originally attempted to check Mahalanobis' Distance for the primary variables, but SPSS doesn't calculate MD when there's missing data for a participant. So, I imputed some values for the missing values, which allowed me to generate a set of MD figures for all of my participants. However, after examining these MD figures, about 120 participants had 'significantly unlikely' (p < .001) MD values. I also noted that overall, the MD values had huge kurtosis (~24) and high skew (~3), so my understanding is that the MD figures aren't reliable anyway.

Does anyone have suggestions on how I should identify multivariate outliers, given my large sample, missing data, reliance on SPSS (and not R or other statistical packages), and ignorance of advanced statistical analysis? :)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What do you want to do with these data after preliminary analysis? You seem focused on the idea that outliers will be problematic: perhaps so, perhaps not. What is an outlier depends on the model used as much as the data. If your data are a mix of variables on quite different ways, it's not obvious that the Mahalanobis method will help. There are many ways of dealing with outliers: see many questions on this site. (Your restriction to SPSS doesn't bite, as software-specific questions and answers are off-topic here.)

Comment: What is the  nature of the different psychology scales you mentioned, categorical or continuous?. Note that we have two types of outliers. If Y is the response and X are the variables, we have outliers in the 1) Y direction and 2) in the X direction. And MD  is a smart way to look at outliers in X-Y plane as you did. But!!! what is your  definition of the center?. If it is the mean it, it might fail. If it is the median how do you calculate a multivariate median?.I want to assume you know quantiles such as the median are more robust to outliers compared to the mean.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Nick and Chamberlain! To provide some more details:

The variables being assessed are ordinal scale items (Likert).

Unfortunately I don't know all of the analyses I'll be performing on these data, although I believe I'll be doing at least the following:

1) Simple descriptives
2) Exploratory factor analysis and confirmatory factor analysis
3) MANCOVAs, MANOVAs, etc.
4) It's likely I'll also be doing hierarchical multiple regressions at some point.
While some of these analyses will be based on the entire sample, some will be on subsamples.
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If they're all ordinal, Mahalanobis makes no sense that I can see, nor do most of the other techniques you mention beyond 1). Nor would I worry about outliers. No technique suitable for ordinal data is especially sensitive to outliers.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. In psychology it's pretty much accepted that we use ordinal scale items as if they were interval scales. I understand this isn't technically 'correct', but it is what we do regardless! :).

Comment: I'm not a psychologist but I am aware of psychological literature that preaches the exact opposite. Indeed the whole NOIR thing comes out of psychology (S.S. Stevens) and while I think that in practice some flexibility is often needed the "ordinal is ordinal and not interval" argument is not nonsensical. Still, that is a (much, much) larger issue.

Comment: Interesting - perhaps my professors have been lying to me all these years! :). Anyway, it seems like MD is not suitable for my purposes, so that's a good start. Thanks for your help.